# What does the verb "indicate" mean in this context

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in "Word Power Made Easy" which was:

> In any case, psychotherapy of one sort or another is the indicated treatment for psychogenic disorders, or for any personality disturbances.

What purpose does the verb "indicate" serve in this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indicated)'s definition 1c of "indicate" is "to demonstrate or suggest the necessity or advisability of", and their example is "the indicated treatment".

Doctors use this word to describe a treatment or medicine that would be good for a particular condition. For example,

> "Aspirin is indicated for occasional mild headaches."